# sqlite 3 column does not exist, even when it's been created

Tags: python, sqlite

I've created a table inside a database, with a column called 'recipeName'. After committing the newly created table to the database, it comes up with this error:

```
    OperationalError: table recipes has no column named recipeName
```

Here's the code for creating the table, and for entering the stuff into the database...

```
       cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \
                                                recipes('id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, recipeName')""")

#Save data to database
conn.commit()

cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO recipes(recipeName) VALUES('%s')""" % (recipeName))
```

I'll be really appreciative of any help I get... this is confusing me quite a lot... I've been working it for days now, and I haven't been able to find a fix...

Thanks in advance :)

Ryan :)

Comment: Did the table already exist? Because if it did that command won't run.  Try "alter table" or "drop table if exist" and then run that.

Comment: The table didn't already exist... it doesn't work before or after creating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS recipes([id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, [recipeName])")
```

you only had one column named : `'id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, recipeName'`

also in sqlite you need to use INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  (not INT and AUTO_INCREMENT)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that, and it's coming up with this: `OperationalError: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error`. I'm not sure how to fix this... Thanks again :)

Comment: basically you want `[id] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`

Comment: Thanks, that got me there! :)